# Problems with explode and get var

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, explode

I have this code

```
$data = explode("/", $_GET['views']);
```

Domain to read is >

> http://myweb.com/loadImage/admin/R2Vxc1ZENFZEbTU0bDdOUjRadnJoZz09/

where admin and R2V.... are session variables.
I tried `print_r($data)` and I get as a result only the first index (loadImage) second and third one are NULL.
`echo $_SESSION` is working. I'm not sure if all have something to do with htaccess file.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Where is "views" coming from I do not see that in the URL

Comment: Sounds like you also wanted to post your ".htaccess" file, especially since you suspect that your issue is caused by that (why ever you do that...).

Comment: I have a function for the views public function get_pages_control(){
    if(isset($_GET['views'])){
    $route = explode("/", $_GET['views']);
    $response = self::get_pages_model($route[0]);
    }else{
    $response = "login";
    }
    return $response;
    }
    
    
}

Comment: htaccess file look like RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?views=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?views=$1&views=$1 [L,QSA]  on localhost is working every single page but online not anymore.